# How to specify implicit arguments for infix operators?

Tags: implicit, idris, infix-operator

Suppose I have an operator

```
infixl 9 @@

(@@) : Tensor [S n] t -> Tensor (S n :: tail) t -> Tensor tail t
```

(where `Tensor` takes a `Vect` and a type, but that's not important here). If I want to specify `tail`, I know that I can add to `a @@ b` by turning `@@` into a function `(@@)` like

```
(@@) {tail=[]} a b
```

but that somewhat defeats the point of it being infix. What's idiomatic?

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a postfix projection operator:

```hs
(.f) : Tensor [S n] t -> Tensor (S n :: tail) t -> Tensor tail t

a.f {tail=[]} b
```

Comment: I get parse errors if I do that. I'm using Idris2 btw. I also have more than one implicit argument

Comment: [if you're sure ...](https://github.com/joelberkeley/spidr/blob/master/src/GaussianProcess.idr#L30) (that's the original)

Comment: based on that code, line 30, `(kernel x x_train) @@ {leading=[]} {head=[samples]} inv @@ {leading=[]} {head=[samples]} y_train` ... adding parentheses doesn't fix it

Comment: @joel I mean the code where you tried to use `.f`

Comment: oh right. That works (at least it compiles). I assumed `.f` and `@@` were equivalent. What's specific about `.f` that means it works where `@@` doesn't?

Comment: @joel `@@` is an infix operator. `.f` is postfix projection operator.

Comment: ok, thanks. I'd not heard of them. I'll have a read.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
let (@@) = (@@) {tail=[]} in a @@ b
```

which is a little long but keeps the syntax